# How can I generate WPF gradient using only one color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gradient

I have a lot of custom control on which various styles applied in my project. For example, I have grid control inside my custom control and I set its background color using dependency property of the custom control like this:

```
<!--MainWindow.xaml-->
<CustomNS:MyCustomControl BackColor="#FF00a6ac"><CustomNS:MyCustomControl/>

<!--Generic.xaml-->
<Grid Background={Binding BackColor}>
```

What I want to do is to make gradient from given color in my dependency property and to apply that gradient on the control. Second color should be generated according to the first color. Namely, second color can be bit darker than the first one.
 To illustrate this, check the image below:

[image]

How can I provide little darker color from the given hex color in the property?

Answer (score 0):

You should use LinearGradientBrush

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/wpf-lineargradientbrush-using-xaml/) you'll find a good example

Comment: I will use LinearGradientBrush already. The problem is to generate second color as darker in code behind.

Comment: Well, I think you should use properties (in code behind or view model, that's no matter), and than bind it to color property poitns to your darker color.